# Difference between "keyChain" and "iCloud keychain" in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

What is the difference between **keyChain** and **iCloud keychain**? 
Are they Same?

Where exactly the login information will be stored **iCloud** or in **File system**?

What happens if i turn off  **iCloud keychain** in device settings?

Please Suggest me a Swift code So I Can store my username and password in my iOS device locally and when connected to Internet it should Sync with iCloud.

I tried to use 
[GitHub - evgenyneu/keychain-swift:](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift)

But im confused with following step given in GitHub:
[Setup with Swift Package Manager](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift#setup-with-swift-package-manager).

I created  **Package.swift** file as given in the step and Pasted

```
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
    name: "KeychainSwift",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift.git",
                 versions: Version(8,0,0)..<Version(9,0,0))
    ]
)
```

This gave me a Warning

> No such module 'PackageDescription'**

Comment: Your keys wouldn't backup to iCloud. That means if you lose your computer you would have to enter all your passwords again. If you have it in iCloud you don't have to.

Comment: So Keychain will store password in device, but will not be updated to iCloud if iCloud Keychain is turned off in device settings. Am I right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It isn't just passwords, it is also all PKI certificates that you have imported, accepted, or have been assigned.  Leo Dabus is correct.  All iCloud keychain passwords and certificates are on both the local computer and synched up to iCloud.  The local keychain is just that, only stored locally.  There are ways to backup just the keychain, but if you're a novice, it just isn't worth the hassle.  Save yourself some time, buy a cheap plan, like $2.99 per month for a 200GB iCloud backup account (if you even need that much.)

Comment: You're not likely to need anywhere near 200GB just for the keychain storage, the free 5GB will probably cover it. Of course if you're backing up more than just the keychain then it may be a different matter.